# Two functions in C collide when used together but work just fine when used alone, what can i do?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I´m trying to make animation by using an address array with an algorithm to calculate the current picture of the animation. 
I got two functions, one is a simple "1 to N counter", the other one includes direction, so i can change the direction somewhere and the function therefore starts to only play the animation for that direction.
The image addresses of all direction are saved in an array so that for example 1-3 are up, 4-6 are right, 7-9 are down and 10-12 are left.

Now to my problem:
If i use both my functions the program stops running.
If i only use one function it all works just fine, and since both functions are basically the same just with an other algorithm i don't understand why it stops when i run both functions.

I generate my address array with my own function so i don't need to have tons of rows with:

```
adr[1] = "bla_1";
adr[2] = "bla_2";
```

... but it doesn´t work as soon as i use 2 'animation functions'.

I tried to not use the function and write the addresses in by hand, now it works just fine. But that's no possible solution for me.
So i guess i made a mistake inside my address array generating function, even so it works just fine as long as i only use one 'animation function'.

______________________________MAIN_______________________________

```
    char* playerAdr[8];

    int count = 0;

    char intString[8];

    int gvPlayerDir = 2; // just for example!

    loadAdrArrPaths( playerAdr, 8, "src/images/player" );

    /*

    playerAdr[0] = "src/images/player_1.png";

    playerAdr[1] = "src/images/player_2.png";

    ...

    playerAdr[7] = "src/images/player_8.png";

    */

    printMultiAnimation( playerAdr, 2, 300, setPos(82,50), 1, gvPlayerDir   );

    //printAnimation( playerAdr, 8, 300, setPos(50,50), 1 );
```

______________________________HEAD_______________________________

```
    void printAnimation( char* adrArr[], int adrNr, int frameTime, sPos pos, bool transparent ){

        int tempInt = ((SDL_GetTicks() - gvTimestamp) / frameTime) % adrNr;

            printSurface( adrArr[tempInt], pos, transparent );

    }

    void printMultiAnimation( char* adrArr[], int adrNr, int frameTime, sPos pos, bool transparent, int dir ){

        int tempInt = (((SDL_GetTicks() - gvTimestamp) / frameTime) % adrNr) + ( adrNr * ( dir - 1 ));

            printSurface( adrArr[tempInt], pos, transparent );

    }

    void loadAdrArrPaths( char* adrArr[], int size, char* path ){


        int count = 0;

        char intString[8];

        char tempPath[size][256];

        while( count < size ){

            sprintf(intString, "%d", count+1);

            strcpy( tempPath[count], path );

            strcat( tempPath[count], "_" );

            strcat( tempPath[count], intString );

            strcat( tempPath[count], ".png" );

            adrArr[count] = tempPath[count];

            //printf("%i   -   %s\n", count, adrArr[count]);

            count++;

        }

    }
```

All i want is to use `printAnimation` and `printMultiAnimation` together, so that i can have some 'simple animations' and some 'direction based animations' at the same time on my screen.
And like i said, if i declare the images addresses 'by hand' it works just fine so I'm pretty sure i do something wrong in my `loadAdrArrPaths` -function. Most likely I screwed up with pointers/references?

I hope someone can and will help me.

Comment: Putting an empty line EVERY other line does NOT improve readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `loadAdrArrPaths`, in the following line:

```
adrArr[count] = tempPath[count];
```

The array `tempPath` is local to `loadAdrArrPaths`, so its contents are no longer available after that function returns.  The cases where this code works do so by luck.  The slightest change can cause the stack to be overwritten, changing the contents of the array.

You can fix it by either having the caller pass the array to `loadAdrArrPaths`, or by dynamically allocating the storage with `malloc`.

Comment: Thanks, i didn´t even thought about that.
I´m now allocating tempPath in loadAdrArrPaths and it works.